# Test to see if an image with json value is broken/ or not there and replace with "no-photo" image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, attributes, return-value

My team and I are using a backend service to grab json data to display images on the frontend. We have a javascript that will display a "no-photo.png" image when their is no value and display the normal product image when their is a value.

The problem is that we will get back values, but the images come back broken because they are not actually there and we have no way of manually removing them.

**My question is:**
Is their a way to determine if the image is broken even if the image has a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an `onerror` callback:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function () {
    this.src = 'noimage.jpg';
};
img.src = 'path/from/json/img.jpg';
```